# Store JSON response into local variable

Tags: jquery

I got some situation here with JQuery. I want to append json data that i get from external resource into local array variable. But it won't work. maybe you guys here can see any logical error in my code and have better solution for me. Thanks a lot.

here's my code:

```
var form_data =
    {
        email : $("#signup_email").val(),
        browser_agent : browser_agent,
        browser_version : browser_version,
        os : os
    }

    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){ 

        form_data.ip = data.host; 
        form_data.countryName =  data.countryName; 
        form_data.region = data.region; 
        form_data.city = data.city; 
    });

    console.log(form_data);
```

The result:

```
Object {email: "myemail@gmail.com", browser_agent: "chrome", browser_version: 30, os: "Win32"}
```

But, I'm expecting result like this one :

```
Object {email: "myemail@gmail.com", browser_agent: "chrome", browser_version: 30, os: "Win32", ip:"192.168.xx.xx", countryName : "indonesia", region : "West Java", city : "batavia"}
```

Any suggestion guys? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log in getJSON response function

```
$.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){ 

    form_data.ip = data.host; 
    form_data.countryName =  data.countryName; 
    form_data.region = data.region; 
    form_data.city = data.city; 
    console.log(form_data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, i find solution. thanks guys

...
var form_data =
    {
    email : $("#signup_email").val(),
    browser_agent : browser_agent,
    browser_version : browser_version,
    os : os,
    device : device
    }

```
get_user_geolocation(function (data){
form_data.ip = data.host; //ip
form_data.countryName = data.countryName; // negara
form_data.region = data.region; //provinsi
form_data.city = data.city; //kota
console.log(form_data)
sign_up(form_data);
});
...
});

});

function get_user_geolocation(callback)
{
$.ajax({
url: "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
callback(data);
}
});
}

function sign_up(form_data)
{
$.ajax({
url: "signup_process.php", 
data: form_data, 
type: "POST", 
dataType: "json",
}).done(function(data) {
alert(data);
}).fail(function(data){
alert("server error");
});
```

}